# Why can't I access User.ContactId from a lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, standard-objects, custom-controller

I can't get a lightning component that references `User.ContactId` to compile. Here's my code:

TestComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="TestController">

</aura:component>
```

TestController.apxc

```
public with sharing class TestController {
    public void testMethod1 () {
        User u = [SELECT ID, ContactId FROM User LIMIT 1];
    }
}
```

When I compile the Apex class, it compiles just fine. But when I subsequently compile the lightning component, I get this error:

```
Failed to save TestComponent.cmp: Invalid definition for null:TestController: SELECT ID, ContactId FROM User LIMIT 1 ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:12 No such column 'ContactId' on entity 'User'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.: Source
```

I know it's ContactId because everything compiles when I remove that field from the query. Also, when I remove the controller field from the component, it compiles just fine.

I know `User.ContactId` exists, and the Apex part compiles fine. But for some reason, the lightning component thinks that `User.ContactId` doesn't exist.

Why is it doing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: This conversation is already quite large, so I have [moved it to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93372/discussion-on-question-by-sarcasticsully-why-cant-i-access-user-contactid-from).

Answer (score 0):

As you said that your controller is working fine so whenever you are adding ***{!User.ContactId}*** in your component you are getting an error.

if you want User contactId, you have to do like this:

***solution 1***

TestController.cmp:

```
<aura:component controller="TestController"  implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="userContactId" type="String"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<div>

   User Contact ID :{!v.userContactId}
</div>
```

TestController.js:

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
     var action = component.get("c.testMethod1");

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {

        var userContactId = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set("v.userContactId", userContactId);
    })
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

})

TestController.apxc:

```
public class TestController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void testMethod1 () {
    Id contactId = [SELECT ID, ContactId FROM User LIMIT 1].contactId;
        system.debug('uu'+contactId);
}
```

}

***solution 2***

if you want without using apex class then also you can do that with this:

TestController.cmp:  Component will be same only.

TestController.js:

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var userId = $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser");
    console.log('userId' ,JSON.stringify(userId.ContactId));
    var userRecord = JSON.stringify(userId);
    component.set("v.userContactId", userRecord.ContactId);
}
```

})

you can try any of above code.